# ERROR 1064 (42000): in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 23

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am compiling the below procedure getting the error not able to find what exactly the issue is

> Mysql server version is  8.0.25-commercial

```
     DELIMITER |
     CREATE PROCEDURE LyrisDbcleanup(OUT p_error_code INT,
                            OUT p_error_msg  VARCHAR(250))
     BEGIN

        DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE v_site_id VARCHAR(2);
        DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT eno FROM  k;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

        SET @AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
        SET @v_name = 'keyanda';
        OPEN c_cur;
        loop1 :LOOP
        FETCH FROM c_cur INTO v_site_id;

       IF done THEN
        CLOSE c_cur;
        LEAVE loop1;
      END IF;
     SET @p_error_code = 0;
     SET @p_error_msg = 'Successfullyprocessed';
     END |

     DELIMITER ;
```

***ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 23***

Comment: You didn't `END LOOP`. See example procedure that uses a cursor here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 1):

I just re-wrote the SP for you.
We don't need `@` everywhere also the `FROM` is optional in `Fetch`.
Loop should be ended with `END LOOP;`

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE LyrisDbcleanup(OUT p_error_code INT,
                                OUT p_error_msg VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE v_site_id VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT eno FROM k;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
    SET v_name = 'keyanda';
    OPEN c_cur;
    loop1: LOOP
        FETCH c_cur INTO v_site_id;

        IF done THEN
            CLOSE c_cur;
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;
        SET p_error_code = 0;
        SET p_error_msg = 'Successfully processed';
    END LOOP;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response now its working missed the End Loop,  error message confused  with different line number,